# How to download mp3s from spotify (with premium subscription)

Tags: windows-10, download, mp3, spotify, drm

I was told that if I subscribe to spotify premium I would be able to download mp3s of all the songs they offer, however after signing up I can't find a "download" button anywhere. Was this just false advertising or an unsubstantiated rumour? How can I download mp3s from spotify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have never been able to download mp3s from Spotify.

Spotify is not a music purchasing service. It is a service for (effectively) renting **access** to music. Both the free (advertisement supported) and paid services rely on this model.

Spotify is a music streaming service which relies upon each track play being protected so that they cannot be freely copied. Otherwise a significant percentage of users would simply subscribe for one month, find and copy the songs they like and then only occasionally resubscribe to update their catalogue. This would not cover the costs associated with paying artists a fair price for their work. (Whether streaming services pay a "fair" price is a story for another day.)

What you *can* do is download the tracks (DRM protected) for use while you lack an internet connection. You are still subject to the restrictions of your subscription and the app occasionally verifying your rights to listen to the files when you have an internet connection.

If you want mp3 files then you will have to purchase the actual albums. Amazon allow you to download mp3 files of purchase tracks.

Answer (score 0):

If you subscribe to the Spotify premium service, you can download Spotify songs to the Spotify desktop application on your computer or Spotify app on your phone, but these downloaded files are just cached files for offline listening on Spotify app, and you can only listen to it on the Spotify application.

If you want to download mp3s from Spotify, you can take a look at AudFun Spotify to mp3 converter. It can download Spotify to mp3 for offline listening at any device or any computer player. Intuitive and easy to use.